# Autoconnect with Cisco Anyconnect on Android

Tags: android, cisco

I work on a Android project and I need to automatically connect with Cisco Anyconnect on a VPN.

I can't find any working informations about autoconnect with Anyconnect.

Is there somebody who has succedded with Anyconnect autoconnection ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

(quotation)

You can use Always On with Trusted Network detection feature of Anyconnect to have the client connect automatically when on an untrusted network.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect44/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-4/configure-vpn.html#ID-1428-000001c7

Regarding saving password, this is not possible. In order to have a seamless user experience, you would need to use client certificates to authenticate the user instead of username and password authentication.